# appendTo to add multiple objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, appendto

I'm trying to figure out if I can use `.appendTo()` to add multiple jquery objects to an existing div container. For example, a sample of my code currently likes like this

```
var parentContainer = $("<div id = 'some_id'></div>"),
    topHalf = $("<div id = 'tophalf'></div>"),
    bottomHalf = $("<div id = 'bottomhalf'><?div>");

(topHalf,bottomHalf).appendTo(parentContainer);
```

Clearly it's not working right now, which is the issue. If I do `(bottomHalf).appendTo(parentContainer)`, it works well. I was just wondering if there is a way to append multiple objects like this to a larger container in a single line of code.

I would hate to have to split it up by having the `bottomHalf` AND `topHalf` have their own lines of code. By the way, I'm also looking to do this for more than two at a certain point (up to 5 or 6), so it could get repetitive extremely fast. Thanks!

Comment: FYI, `topHalf,bottomHalf` is the application of the [**comma operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator). Both expressions are evaluated and the result of the second expression is returned. So, `(topHalf,bottomHalf).appendTo(parentContainer);` is equivalent to `bottomHalf.appendTo(parentContainer);`.

Answer (score 5):

You could just use [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to do this:

```
parentContainer.append(topHalf, bottomHalf);
```

However, if you're really hell-bent on using `appendTo`, you can first [`add()`](http://api.jquery.com/add/) the bottomHalf to the topHalf, and then call `appendTo`:

```
topHalf.add(bottomHalf).appendTo(parentContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use documentFragments as well. jQuery themselves use it behind the scenes, even for append, but they also encourage it's use and even with the append function so you can use it as an object that is a decorated collection before being inserted into the dom which thus causes a dom reflow which is costly so you only want to do this once or as little as possible. Document Fragments can also help when there is conditional logic being used to determine what parts are to be appended before actually being inserted into the browsers dom.

- http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/
- https://coderwall.com/p/o9ws2g

**Append()**

Your specific example it could look like something similar to this:

```
$(function () {
    var documentFragment = $(document.createDocumentFragment());
    var parentContainer = documentFragment.append($("<div id='some_id'>parentContainer</div>"));
    var topHalf = $("<div id='tophalf'>topHalf</div>");
    var bottomHalf = $("<div id='bottomhalf'>bottomHalf<?div>");

    /*
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment

    You can decorate the documentFragment based on your specific conditions, then based on criteria and conditions you always pass one object to be attached to the dom. Since the document fragment is in memory and not part of the main DOM tree, appending children to it does not cause page reflow (computation of element's position and geometry). Consequently, using document fragments often results in better performance.
    */

    parentContainer.append(topHalf, bottomHalf);

    // only one 'reflow' causing dom append. all the previous ones are behind the scenes and allow you to construct and build without reflows. documentFragment is very helpful for decorating objects and then using them to do a final append that actually does cause a reflow.
    $('#result').append(parentContainer);
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/suhnmm6b/6/

**AppendTo()**

Here is the inverse using the appendTo() as you asked but still using a documentFragment collection which is then appended as one object to the parent container.

```
$(function () {
    var documentFragment = $(document.createDocumentFragment());
    var parentContainer = $("<div id='some_id'>parentContainer</div>");
    var topHalf = documentFragment.append($("<div id='tophalf'>topHalf</div>"));
    var bottomHalf = documentFragment.append($("<div id='bottomhalf'>bottomHalf<?div>"));

    /*
    https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment

    You can decorate the documentFragment based on your specific conditions, then based on criteria and conditions you always pass one object to be attached to the dom. Since the document fragment is in memory and not part of the main DOM tree, appending children to it does not cause page reflow (computation of element's position and geometry). Consequently, using document fragments often results in better performance.
    */
    (documentFragment).appendTo(parentContainer);
    // only one 'reflow' causing dom append. all the previous ones are behind the scenes and allow you to construct and build without reflows. documentFragment is very helpful for decorating objects and then using them to do a final append that actually does cause a reflow.
    $('#result').append(parentContainer);
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/z34yzk7x/3/

**References:**

- http://davidwalsh.name/documentfragment
- http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_createdocumentfragment.asp
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createDocumentFragment
- https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow?csw=1
- http://ejohn.org/apps/workshop/adv-talk/#6
- http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2281-jquery-appends-multiple-elements-using-efficient-document-fragments.htm

Comment: It's also worth noting that jQuery uses document fragment for their append too, BUT this doesn't mean you can't still use it as a preliminary clipboard object that then gets added to the dom.